# IOS web browser, "will-change" cause render issue

Tags: html, css, reactjs, will-change

Css attribute "will-change" make animation performance better. But seem like it'll disable some render in IOS mobile browser under special condition.

The behavior of following code in IOS mobile browser:

1. Click "click me", add count to `length`;
2. Render Component with new `length`;
3. "value" show wrong `length`, "same value" show right `length`.

The difference between "value" and "same value" is css code, i think maybe "will-change" trigger IOS mobile browser optimize render html. The correct `length` in "value" has been optimized.

So please someone explain this strange issue. Thanks.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [length, setLength] = useState(0);

  const onClick = () => setLength(length + 1);

  const list = Array.from({ length }).fill("");
  const items = list.map(() => {
    return <div className="item">placeholder</div>;
  });

  return (
    <div className="container">
      { /* has css "will-change" */ }
      <div className="create" onClick={onClick}>
        Click me
      </div>
      {items}
      { /* has css "position: relative", "box-shadow" */ }
      <div className="length"> value: {length}</div>
      <div> same value: {length} </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
.length {
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px red;
}

.create {
  will-change: transform;
}

.container {
  font-size: 28px;
}
```

[Bug Demo, open with iphone browser](https://myh7m.csb.app)

[Bug video, if don't have iphone](https://cdn-health.zhongan.com/magiccube/resource/rl/4g8ZM4GEek.mp4)

[Source code](https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-worker-myh7m)

Answer (score 1):

Hope i can provide some help here:

First of all, you say

> Css attribute "will-change" make animation performance better.

And that's not true, quate from MDN:

> "will-change is intended to be used as a last resort, in order to try to deal with existing performance problems. It should not be used to anticipate performance problems."

> "Use sparingly. The normal behavior for optimizations that the browser make is to remove the optimizations as soon as it can and revert back to normal. But adding will-change directly in a stylesheet implies that the targeted elements are always a few moments away from changing and the browser will keep the optimizations for much longer time than it would have otherwise."

A very important part missing from the summary is under the "Remove will-change After the Changes Are Done".

also, remember that will-change cost memory and Browser will need approx. 200ms to apply optimization.

The script runs fine if you

- Removed the position relative
- Remove the will-change
- Zoom in after a click, values updates.
- Adding a key to your component will force it to update
  `<div key={length} className="length"> value: {length}</div>`

You would take a look at this to get more info on how will-change.

[How to use and how works CSS' will-change property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26907265/how-to-use-and-how-works-css-will-change-property)

Comment: Is there an answer why "position: relative" and "box-shadow" will make this happen ?